# Явное преобразование типов

Tags: c#

Создал несколько переменных. Решил поиграться с преобразованием типов:

```
int x = 11;
double y = 334.33;
short z = 1;

x = (int) y;
z = (short) x;
z = (short) y;

Console.WriteLine (x);
```

Решил посмотреть на результат, а тут:

```
334
```

Почему так?

Comment: а что не так?..

Comment: @TEA А дело в том, что x равен 11, а не 334. Я же просто поменял тип переменной, а не ее значение.

Comment: x = (int) y; а это что или это рофл такой?

Comment: @TEA Я что то не вдупляю ( . x = (int) y; Ну это я поменял тип Y с double на int; Потом вывел в консоль X, а X же равен 11

Comment: так ты y присвоил,почитай основы,прежде чем с такими вопросами на СО лезть. https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/ Вот тебе прекрасный туториал по си шарпу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int x = 11;
double y = 334.33;
short z = 1;



Console.WriteLine ( (int)(x) );
Console.WriteLine ( (int)(y) );
Console.WriteLine ( (int)(z) );
```

или вот явное преобразование типов

```
int y2 = (int)y;
Console.WriteLine ( y2 );
```